# show algorithm to compute square root converge.

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Consider the calculating the square root as follow:

Let's say we want to compute square root of $x>0$, pick a number $g_1>0$, then if $|g_1^2-x| < 0.00001$ then done. Else, let $g_2=\frac{g+\frac{x}{g}}{2.0}$. Show that the algorithm eventually stops. Or,  $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n = x$.

Comment: Why do you say it is slow?  It is one of the faster ones, especially if you start close to $\sqrt x$.  If you prove the error is reduced by more than some constant factor you are there.  What have you tried?

Comment: Here is what I observed: $2gg'=g^2+x$,  so if $g^2$ and $x$ are close enough then gg'=x. Please help! I did not say that it is slow. I meant show if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  write $g_1=\sqrt g+e_1$, so $e_1$ is the error of your first approximation.  Let $e_2=g_2-\sqrt g$.  Show that $e_2$ is smaller than $e_1$ by a factor you can bound away from $1$.  Then $e_n$ is smaller than $e_1$ by more than the $n-1$ power of that factor and you are done.